# Need help google testing a unique Id generator

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a C++ class that generates unique IDs in the following fashion.

```
class Foo
{
  static int seed;
public:
  const int Uid;
  Foo() : Uid(seed++) {}
}

int Foo::seed = 0;
```

Now I'm using Google Test to test this Id generator using:

```
Foo foo;
EXPECT_EQ(0, foo.Uid);
Foo foo2;
EXPECT_EQ(1, foo2.Uid);
```

This test **passes when I debug it** but fails when I actually run it, giving me IDs of 2 and 3 instead. Can someone help me figure out why? Is Google test running two of these tests back-to-back or something?

Answer (score 5):

One of characteristics of good tests is repeatability with not depending on tests order execution.

You have a singleton, and you use it in a bad way. If we assume there are no memory problems, then what most likely happens, is that the object of type `Foo` is somewhere created, and that your tests are getting executed in different order for debug and normal runs. That would explain different results.

How to fix? The simplest hack would be to add a method to reset the counter, and call it in `setUp()`. To fix it properly, you need to think how to remove that singleton.

Comment: Pretty much- this is why global mutable state is bad.

Answer (score 3):

[BЈовић's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163308/2466336) will get you there. It's likely that somewhere else in your test code another instance of Foo is created that increases the value of the static member.

This may be a less hacky solution and possibly useful if adding a public reset method is not applicable (i.e. you don't want to add test-specific code to your API):

1. Mock classes. Add a class that dervies from Foo. Change the access level of your static variable from private to protected and add the new reset method to the protected class. You can then refactor your test code to run off of the derived class.
2. Make FooTester a friend of Foo. Via class friend ship you're allowing your test code more manipulation over the class under test.

I recommend going with the mock route. Keeps the original class clean of any test specific hacks and allows you to be more aware of any exposures in its interface.

Comment: For mock classes, he needs to use dependency injection, and redesign. But good suggestion.